# want to add or want to merge two new arrays into 3 earlier arrays

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

```
array_1 = {"challenge_id":"1","user_id":"2","username":"abc","challenge_balance":"1million","bet":"lyf","challenge_name":"disaster","plan":"enjoy","challenge_type":"Me","c_type":"challenge"}

array 2 = {"challenge_id":"8","user_id":"2","username":"abc","challenge_balance":"1million","bet":"lyf","challenge_name":"disaster","plan":"enjoy","challenge_type":"Me","c_type":"challenge"},

array_3 = {"challenge_id":"9","user_id":"2","username":"abc","challenge_balance":"1million","bet":"lyf","challenge_name":"disaster","plan":"enjoy","challenge_type":"Me","c_type":"challenge"}
```

another array from different query

```
array 1= {"project_id":"1","project_name":"2","description":"testing","p_type":"project","project_balance":"1trillion","hatred_ressented":"dontknow"}

array 2 = {"challenge_id":"9","user_id":"2","username":"abc","challenge_balance":"1million","bet":"lyf","challenge_name":"disaster","plan":"enjoy","challenge_type":"Me","c_type":"challenge"}
```

I want result should be in 3 arrays 
which means the first array should be combined with first from both
the second array as combined of second from both
the third array as array 1 with null.

Answer (score 0):

Simply merge them with [`array_merge()`](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_merge.asp)

```
$merge_array = array_merge(first_array, second_array);
```

Example:

```
$one =  array('one'=>1, 'two'=>2);

$two =  array('three'=>1, 'four'=>2);

$three =  array('five'=>1, 'six'=>2);

$merge_array = array_merge($one, $two);


$merge_three = array_merge($merge_array, $three);

print_r($merge_three);

//THE result

Array ( [one] => 1 [two] => 2 [three] => 1 [four] => 2 [five] => 1 [six] => 2 )
```

Comment: ankit sir, in result i am getting only one array whereas i need 3 arrays

Comment: Please don't call sir, and for you query use foreach.

Comment: brother, will you please elaborate or tell me using coding